# Reassigning Multidimensional Arrays in Java Problem

Tags: java

I have the following problem

```
double myArray [][][] = new double [3][][];
double d = 100.0;
double [][] myArray2 = new double [1][1];
```

Which of the following will not cause any problem at compile time or runtime?
Select 2 options

```
A. myArray [0] = d;
B. myArray [0] = myArray2;
C. myArray [0] = myArray2 [0];
D. myArray2 [1][1] = d;
E. myArray2 = myArray [0]
```

The answer is B and E, but I don't understand why. The problem is based on reassigning multi-dimensional arrays to each other, but using arrays that were initialized with separate dimensions. So, when I look at the answer for B, I don't understand how myArray[0] = myArray2 are both the same dimension and the same for answer myArray2 = myArray[0]. Could someone explain this to me. Many thanks.

Comment: Because `myArray` is essentially an array of `myArray2`s.

Answer (score 3):

Java assigns variables *references* to complex objects, such as arrays. Reassigning an array variable sets a new reference, it does not copy the array. That means it does not matter what the dimensions of the old reference target array and the new reference target array are.

Multidimensional arrays in Java don't really exist and are actually arrays of arrays. Each nested array can have a different dimension ("jagged array").

```
int small[] = new int[5];
int big[] = new int[42];
small = big; // reference is set. no problem, small == big
big[0] = 1337;
System.out.println(small[0]); // 1337; since both references reference the same array
```

Array indices start at `0`, so `array[0]` is the first element in an array.

With the above information is should be simple to figure out which of the assignment statements are valid to the compiler and which could throw an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
double myArray [][][] = new double [3][][];
double d = 100.0;
double [][] myArray2 = new double [1][1];
```

Which of the following will not cause any problem at compile time or runtime? Select 2 options

```
A. myArray [0] = d;
B. myArray [0] = myArray2;
C. myArray [0] = myArray2 [0];
D. myArray2 [1][1] = d;
E. myArray2 = myArray [0]
```

> The answer is B and E, but I don't understand why.

Remember that multi-dimensional arrays are arrays of arrays. So `myArray[0]` is a `2D` array since `myArray` is a `3D` array.

- A. You are assigning a double value to a cell that is expecting a `2D` array (error)
- B. you are assigning a `2D` array to a cell that is expecting a `2D` array (okay)
- C. You are Assigning a `1D` array to a cell that expects a `2D` array (error)
- D. The indices (`1`) is out of bounds. Zero based so should only be `0's`  (error) - thanks @matt
- E. You are assigning a `2D` array to a value that is a `2D` array (okay)

SO B and E are the ones that are allowed.

Comment: @matt ugh.  I glossed over it . Yep.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Multidimensional arrays are actually arrays of arrays. When you declare `double myArray[][][]`, you are creating a 3D array, or an array of 2D arrays.

Answer B: `myArray[0] = myArray2;` is valid because `myArray[0]` is a 2D array, and `myArray2` is also a 2D array. You are assigning one 2D array to another, which is allowed.

Answer E: `myArray2 = myArray[0]` is also valid for same reason. `myArray[0]` is a 2D array, and you are assigning it to `myArray2`, which is also a 2D array.

The other options are not valid because they are trying to assign incompatible types. For example, option A is trying to assign a double to a 2D array, which is not allowed. Option C is trying to assign a 1D array to a 2D array, and option D is trying to assign a value to an index that does not exist in the array.